# Insert "and" before the last element jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var swTitle = {};
var favorite = [];
    $.each($("input[name='Title']:checked"), function() {
        favorite.push($(this).val());
        console.log($("input[name='Title']:checked"));
    });
    swTitle.domain = favorite;   
var List = {};
    for (var m = 0; m < favorite.length; m++) {
        var swTitleObj = [];
        $.each($('input[name="' + swTitle.domain[m] + '"]:checked'), function() {
            console.log(swTitle.domain[m]);
            swTitleObj.push($(this).attr("class"));
            console.log(swTitleObj);
        });
        List[swTitle.domain[m]] = swTitleObj;
    }
var swSkillData = " ";
    $.each(List, function(key, value) {
        console.log(key + ":" + value);
        swSkillData += '<li>' + key + '&nbsp' + ':' + '&#160' + value + '</li>';
    });
Output will be like:
  Fruits:Apple,Banana,Orange,Grapes
  I want my output be like:
  Fruits:Apple,Banana,Orange & Grapes
```

I have an array of keys and values separated by commas. I want to insert "and" and remove the comma before the last checked element. Kindly help me out with this issue.

Comment: Can you create a JSfiddle for the work you have done till now. So that it will be easier to understand and solve, than the give code.

Comment: The code shown seems to be producing output as a string of HTML with `<li>` elements, not a comma-separated list, so where are the commas you're talking about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
str = str.replace(/,(?=[^,]*$)/, 'and')
```

I solved my own issue. I replaced my last comma with "and" using the above regex. Thanks to Regex!!!

Answer (score 0):

I think you can reduce your code, with an option of adding `and` before the last element like,

```
var inputs=$("input[name='Title']:checked"),
    len=inputs.length,
    swSkillData='',
    counter=0;// to get the last one
$.each(inputs, function() {
    sep=' , '; // add comma as separator
    if(counter++==len-1){ // if last element then add and
       sep =' and ';
    }
    swSkillData += '<li>' + this.value + // get value
            '&nbsp' + ':' + '&#160' +
             this.className + // get classname
             sep + // adding separator here
             '</li>';

});
```

Updated, with and example of changing `,` to `&`

```
$.each(List, function(key, value) {
    console.log(key + ":" + value);
    var pos = value.lastIndexOf(',');// get last comma index
    value = value.substring(0,pos)+' & '+value.substring(pos+1);
    swSkillData += '<li>' + key + '&nbsp' + ':' + '&#160' + value + '</li>';
});
```

**Snippet**

```js
var value ='Apple,Banana,Orange,Grapes';var pos = value.lastIndexOf(',');// get last comma index
        value = value.substring(0,pos)+' & '+value.substring(pos+1);
console.log(value);
```

Comment: @suna I have updated my answer with your existing code and added a snippet to replace last `,` with `&`.

Comment: I have worked with your solution but it does not seem to work @Rohan

Comment: May be you are missing something, otherwise my snippet is working well. If you can show me your code with HTML(Fiddle or Snippet) then I can help you more in finding your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an easy and customizable form of doing it.

(SOLUTION IS GENERIC)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var ara = ['Apple','Banana','Orange','Grapes'];
  displayAra(ara);

  function displayAra(x) {
    var str = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
      if (i + 1 == x.length) {
        str = str.split('');
        str.pop();
        str = str.join('');
        str += ' and ' + x[i];
        console.log(str);
        $('.displayAra').text(str);
        break;
      }
      str += x[i] + ',';
    }
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Fruits :     <span class="displayAra"></span>
```

Comment: Thanks Barot. But it does not seem to help me out

Comment: It generates the exact output as you have mentioned in question. I can help you if you want to fit it in your code, if you want me to.. @suna

Comment: Yes please help me out Barot

Comment: @Barot. Do you have any solution for my issue?